# I want to integrate ad to my app, but the problem is that the ( Type mismatch. Required: Context!, Found Fragment class)

Tags: android-fragments, admob, android-context, kotlin-multiplatform, native-ads

I want to integrate ad to my app, but the problem is that the

`MobileAds.initialize(this){ initStatus-> not work this method( onCreateView)`

But I am use this method( onCreate:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this){ initStatus-> this working...  Activity class,
```

But I want to use when I add ads to a fragment instead of an activity.

Can anyone tell me the working code for it?

I had tried some methods, but they didn't work. If the code is placed in an activity it works correctly

Here is the code I tried for Fragment:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Inside a `Fragment`, use either `requireActivity()` or `requireContext()` because the `MobileAds.initialize()` needs a Context & you are passing a Fragment instance. Also this initialisation should be done as early as possible, for example via `Application` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in fragment by giving the context of activity.

Update your code:-

```
MobileAds.initialize(this)
```

To:-

```
MobileAds.initialize(getActivity())
```

or you can initialize an activity variable in the fragment once the fragment is attached to the activity.

Comment: `getActivity()` is `nullable`, either use it with null-safe operator like `getActivity()?.let { ... }` or use `requireActivity()`.

Comment: I agree, missed that as I was just pointing out to use activity context. Thanks for the update, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using AdMob for displaying ads and that is important to mention.
Second of all, the API for initializing ads can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds#public-static-void-initialize-context-context,-oninitializationcompletelistener-listener) and you can see that it requires passing a Context argument and a specific listener:

```
public static void initialize (Context context,OnInitializationCompleteListener listener)
```

In your onCreateView method, this is a reference to the Fragment, unlike in the onCreate of the Activity where this is a reference to the Activity which acts as a context itself.

Since you have a view in your onCreateView method, you can get the context from there ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext())).

You can also use the [requireActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireActivity()) or [requireContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireContext()) methods.

Comment: I try this all method is not working , I want to connect each every five posts with ads so I need help sir, how to connect MobileAds.initialize(this) some other method

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside Fragment will return Fragment itself so
`MobileAds.initialize(requireActivity())` or `MobileAds.initialize(requireContext())`

DON'T USE `getActivity()` IT'S NULLABLE